# Como pegar o bit menos significativo de um caractere e esconder num arquivo de imagem?

Tags: c

O programa que verifica se um determinado LSB foi alterado, como proceder?

Comment: É uma questão ampla, você deveria separar um código em partes específicas e a medida que for evoluindo, podes fazer questões pontuais colocando o código que está desenvolvendo, tem alguns usuários que podem lhe ajudar se seguir este método... Considere fazer um [tour] para verificar as melhores práticas ao fazer uma pergunta. Boa Sorte. Não sei se é o que está procurando mas vou deixar essa dica : https://github.com/samuelcouch/c-steganography

Comment: Acredito que pode ajudar, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você está enrolado no conceito de esteganografia. Deixa eu tentar explicar um pouco aqui, e com isso você deve entender o suficiente para começar uma implementação:

Primeiro, uma imagem pode ser entendida como uma sequência de (altura × largura) pixels, cada um destes sendo um número inteiro que codifica a claridade (no caso de uma imagem em tons de cinza) ou a intensidade das componentes vermelha, verde e azul de cada pixel.

Observe que, como há muitos (pelo menos 256) valores possíveis para a intensidade de cada pixel (ou de cada componente RGB de cada pixel), a diferença entre dois valores vizinhos é muito pequena, e praticamente imperceptível quando o pixel é renderizado. Por isso, se esse último bit menos significativo do pixel/componente é zero ou um, alguém vendo a imagem não vai perceber a diferença. Portanto, você pode esconder um dado nesses bits menos significativos sem que alguém que não sabe o que está acontecendo perceba.

Pegue, então, a sua mensagem, e enxergue-a como uma sequência de bits. Por exemplo, a *string* `"Wikipedia\0"` é vista como a sequência

```
0111 0111 0110 1001 0110 1011 0110 1001 0111 0000
0110 0101 0110 0100 0110 1001 0110 0001 0000 0000
```

(note o *byte* zero para marcar o fim da mensagem).

Então você pega cada um desses 80 bits e esconde, em ordem, nos bits menos significativos dos 80 primeiros pixels (ou dos 80 primeiros componentes) da sua imagem.

Vê se com isso você consegue entender suficientemente bem o que precisa fazer de modo a poder fazer outras perguntas, mais específicas, e postando algum código conforme as regras do *site*.